# How to connect Google VM Instance to Google SQL Instance and use it both to run Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, sql, google-cloud-platform

Dears,
Its been 2-3 weeks since I've started learning how to host my websites on Google VM instance, I've installed Vesta Cpanel and it will install PHP, apache, MySQL, PHPMyAdmin .. etc all the necessary software's to run my site without problems.

But I heard from my friend that its better to run the database on a specific server not on the same instance .. since I'm hosting eCommerce website and the database is gonna be big. I want to choose the best option and I heard that its:

1- Hosting my website code (Wordpress script) to Google VM Instance.
2- Hosting the Wordpress databases on Google SQL instance.
3- connect the VM instance to the SQL instance
4- create my database using the SQL instance and run it successfully together.

please let me know if I'm wrong.

I've created the SQL instance, I gave 2 access for this instance one from my local machine (mac laptop) and the second one from the VM instance and its successfully worked.

Both instance the VM and the SQL are on the same project in Google cloud.

But when I want to edit the wp-config.php file on Wordpress and add the username, password, hostname it won't connect.

I think the problem is with the (localhost) hostname, I don't know how to make it work since I'm not installing the SQL on the VM instance, I want to run it from the SQL instance  ...

I heard about the proxy but I don't know if I need it and I don't know how to connect with it.

Please help me.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if it's completely different on the google systems, but generally if you are connecting to a database on another server, you would just replace the "localhost" hostname, with the IP address of the database server. Does this SQL instance have a static IP address?

Have you tried looking at:
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-ip

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? If so kindly post an answer, it will certainly help the community. If not please provide the content of  wp-config.php and the details on how you configured the access to your Cloud SQL instance and any errors displayed.  A similar setup is discussed [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-cloud-sql-discuss/pgTB5n-kfbo)